# When using loaders with webpack, are there any differences in referring to the loader with the "-loader" postfix?

Tags: webpack

I've seen different examples around, such as these two:

1. [An example showing the "-loader" postfix after the style and css loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#configuration),
2. [Another including the loaders without the "-loader" postfix.](http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#config-file)

I've tested it and it *seems* to work in both cases.  Does webpack test for and include it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference.

In the past this was problematic. If you had both [css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css) and [css-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader) installed it could fail to load when using `loader: 'css'` kind of definition. This doesn't seem to be an issue anymore.

[resolveLoader.moduleTemplates](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader-moduletemplates) can be used to control this behavior in detail if needed.